# AWS Redis Reader endpoint and ioredis

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, redis, amazon-elasticache, ioredis

We want our Redis to be more scalable and we want to be able to add more read instances.

I am trying to use this new Reader endpoint: https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/06/amazon-elasticache-launches-reader-endpoint-for-redis

However I dont see any easy or automated way for `ioredis` to use that approach where I can set up which endpoint will be for writes and which one for reads. Even here I can see the recommended approach at the end is to "manually split": https://github.com/luin/ioredis/issues/387

Do you know any existing solution or good approach where I can set up which endpoints will be used for writes and which one will be used for reads?

The most straightforward for me right now is some kind of "proxy" layer, where I will create two instances of Redis and I will send all writes to the primary endpoint and all reads to Reader endpoint. However I would prefer some better (or well tested) approach.

PS: I tried to "hack it" with `Cluster` functionality of `ioredis`, but even the simple connection without any functionality and one - primary endpint - fails with `ClusterAllFailedError: Failed to refresh slots cache.`
(To have Reader endpoint enabled - the Cluster mode must be off)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just note about how it ended

We had two instances (or reused the same instance if URL was same)

```
redis = new Redis(RKT_REDIS_URL.href, redisOptions)
if (RKT_REDIS_READER_URL.href === RKT_REDIS_URL.href) {
    redisro = redis
} else {
    redisro = new Redis(RKT_REDIS_READER_URL.href, redisOptions)
}
```

And then used first for writes and other for reads.

```
 redis.hmset(key, update)
 redisro.hmget(key, field)
```

However after some time we have adopted clustered redis and it is much better and can recommend it. Also the `ioredis` npm module is capable of using it seemlessly (you dont have to configure anything, you just put there configure endpoint which i.e. AWS provides and thats it).

This was our configuration

```
redisOptions.scaleReads = 'master'
redis = new Redis.Cluster([RKT_REDIS_URL.href], redisOptions)
```

The options for scaleReads are

> scaleReads is "master" by default, which means ioredis will never send
> any queries to slaves. There are other three available options:
>
> "all": Send write queries to masters and read queries to masters or
> slaves randomly. "slave": Send write queries to masters and read
> queries to slaves.
>
> https://github.com/luin/ioredis

Comment: According to your configuration, your primary read client is the connection from the reader endpoint. Since you're using scaleReads with 'master', in case your reader endpoint faces too many requests, it falls back to the master. This is what you expected, if I am inferring correctly?

Also for the cluster approach you didn't need to put the reader endpoint, at all?

Comment: @SowmenRahman - its almost two years and I am not in that company anymore. If I remember correctly for clustered mode you have just one endpoint and ioredis automatically knows how to reach master/slaves with it. Also we ended up probably with having `.scaleReads = 'slave'` as it distributes the load properly.

Comment: = with clustered redis you dont need `redisro` at all